# Banco de dados offline em app Phonegap

Tags: sqlite, apache-cordova

Estou criando um app com o Phonegap e preciso consumir/manipular informações de uma base SQLite existente dentro do meu diretório `WWW` mas em 3 dias procurando tutoriais só encontrei formas de criar o banco de dados na hora e então inserir dados nele. Alguém tem uma "luz" no fim do tunel ai pra me ajudar? Se não houver uma maneira de fazer isso, pelo menos que me dêem um outro caminho para ter uma base de dados dentro do phonegap e acessá-la sem precisar da net.

Comment: Uma pergunta paralela aqui. Através do Phonegap conseguimos criar um aplicativo usando HTML5, jQuery. Mas uma pergunta, talvez no-sense... depois de terminar o aplicativo tem como compilar ele em **.apk** para funcionar no Android ? Ou quando se fala **aplicativo** é apenas para usar no navegador ?

Comment: Você tem que entender que o phonegap cria um "browser" compilado com seu código fonte. Tecnicamente (falando a grosso modo) se você pegar seu site hoje e jogar dentro do phonegap, você vai conseguir "instalar" ele no celular... lógico que não é tão simples, mas em tese é isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar um plugin para isso.

Para instalar use o comando: cordova plugin add https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Para poder usar o Banco em qualquer lugar do meu código, criei um variável chamada DB no início da página index.js, ficando mais ou menos assim o começo da página:

```
var db;
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "DB"});
db.transaction(function(tx) {
        // Cria a Tabela "tabela_testes"
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabela_teste (id integer primary key, titulo text)');
        // Adiciona um elemento a tabela
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO tabela_teste (titulo) VALUES (?)", ["Meu primeiro post."]);

        // Faz uma busca na tabela
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM tabela_teste;", [], function(tx, res) {
            alert("Quantidade Resultados: " + res.rows.length);
            for (var i = 0;i<res.rows.length;i++){
                alert("Linha "+i+": "+res.rows.item(i).titulo);
            }
          });
    });
```

Para Fazer uma query em qualquer parte do Aplicativo mesmo fora da página index.js, basta usar a variável DB e a query que deseja como no código acima.

Fonte: https://diariodoprogramadortda.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/trabalhando-com-sqlite-no-cordovaphonegap/

Comment: No caso não teve insert do campo ID, ele fica vazio ou auto increment por ser primary key?